# The sharp decline Statistics of website

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console

My website has had 10 months ago, the statistics are very high. 
Very high ...

But after 10 days of server failure, Marm was 20 times less.

I got lost for a long time without making a mistake, do ... 
I am the source of links that they've hired a writer to pen the final results are seen.

But a strange thing: 
Approximately every two months and was hit again 20 more times and then low again after 10 days!

my website url : www.sooran.com (food.sooran.com)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I know that after a period of outage that is significant, it can take a while to get back in Google's SERPs. You remain within the index most times. But with 20 days of outage, that may be over the limit and may require a re-spider and refresh. However, after 10 months, I would have expected that to happen already. I too experienced a week of outage a few years ago and it took about a month to begin climbing back quickly. Have you tried fetch as Google or submitting a fresh sitemap in Google Webmaster Tools? There maybe another condition that exists that is harming your site.

Comment: thanks @closetnoc
I  have't google webmaster  message or alert! 
Everything is great !

Comment: If you do a site:example.com in Google, do you see all your pages indexed? That is, if you have 200 pages, does Google say 10 out of 200? (Or something like that.) If so, perhaps there is a penalty unrealted to the outage that was applied at the same time that is taking you out of the SERPs. Keep in mind that site rank metrics include up-time which speaks to domain quality. I would have thought by now you would be headed back if that metric was *triggered*. Otherwise, I think I would be looking for something else just in case. I will have to think on this a bit.

Answer (score 1):

## Google can not index your site!

When it says the bot cannot access it, it means just that! Google can no longer see your content!

Is it possible you have changed something in your robots.txt file?

Other than that, it could be your .htaccess (have you tried different combinations, like with, without www.?) - Your server may have been comprimised :  Google web tools will tell you if it has.

I'd try to get this fixed ASAP - indexing usually takes less than a month.. 3 weeks on average in my experience. Fix the problem and manually re-submit the site for indexing.

***Update***: After Googling your site using `site: http://sooran.com/`, I couldn't find anything. I'd wager it's a redirect problem. Whatever you did in September of last year is likely the culprit.

Comment: In `http://food.sooran.com/robots`. Beds did not see a problem!